# Generic method as functional programming using java.util.Function

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am not sure can we write the generic method as a function programming using Java 8 lamda expression as below

**Generic method**

```
public <T> MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
    return mongoClient
            .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.getDatabase())
            .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
}
```

I want to convert this generic method to generic functional lamda expression as below

```
public BiFunction<String, Class<T>, T> getCollection = (collectionName, typeParameterClass) -> {
    return mongoClient
            .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.getDatabase())
            .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
};
```

From the above code I have an error on type `T` and `typeParameterClass`

[image]

**Update 1**

While implementing the method suggested by @Clashsoft the second argumenent is `Class<Object>` instead of `Class<T>`

```
repository.getCollectionFactory().apply("", Category.class);
```

[image]

Comment: Your signature should at minimum be `BiFunction<String, Class<T>, MongoCollection<T>>` (though I don't think that'll work either), as the return type is `MongoCollection<T>`, and not `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with a field. You can however create another method / getter with a type parameter:

```java
public <T> BiFunction<String, Class<T>, MongoCollection<T>> getCollectionFactory() {
    return  (collectionName, typeParameterClass) -> {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.getDatabase())
                .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
    };
};
```

Keep in mind you have to specify the type when calling the method:

```java
repository.<Category>.getCollectionFactory().apply("test", Category.class)
```

Or use a variable with an explicit type:

```java
BiFunction<String, Class<Category>, MongoCollection<Category>> factory = repository.getCollectionFactory();
factory.apply("test", Category.class)
```

Of course, you can already do this with the regular old `getCollection` method:

```java
BiFunction<String, Class<Category>, MongoCollection<Category>> factory = repository::getCollection;
```

So the usefulness of the factory method is questionable.

Comment: I think that should be `BiFunction<String, Class<T>, MongoCollection<T>>` since the function returns a `MongoCollection<T>`.

Comment: @khelwood thanks, I copied that part from the question. Fixed!

Comment: @Clashsoft While implementing this method repository.getCollectionFactory().apply("test" ,Category.class)); the second argument is   Class<Object> but it should be Class<T>

Comment: @SanJaisy yes that's a problem you'll have a lot with this approach. You need to specify the type argument in the `getCollectionFactory` call: `repository.<Category>.getCollectionFactory().apply("test", Category.class)`. That's why I'd try to stick with the regular method.

Comment: It's possible with a field if the class is generic no?

Comment: @YassinHajaj - can you please provide an example

Comment: @YassinHajaj yes, but I think in OPs case that wouldn't be useful. A repository would usually have multiple collections, that way you could only have one.

Answer (score 1):

The `BiFunction` has wrong the third type (the result type) that should be `MongoCollection<T>`:

```
public BiFunction<String, Class<T>, MongoCollection<T>> getCollection = (name, type) -> 
    mongoClient
        .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.getDatabase())
        .getCollection(name, type);
```

Also note the `T` must be the class generic parameter as long as `getCollection` is no longer a method but a field.

```
public class ClassHavingGetCollectionField<T> {
   ...
}
```

... otherwise you need to define a method with a generic type *returning* such functional interface implementation:

```
public <T> BiFunction<String, Class<T>, MongoCollection<T>> getCollectionBiFunction() {
    return (name, type) ->
         mongoClient
             .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.getDatabase())
             .getCollection(name, type);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, what is the type for T ?